# Drupal 7 function ajax responder

Tags: ajax, drupal, module, callback, drupal-7

I am building a complex AJAX based solution as a module into a Drupal 7 site. I decided not to write a standalone PHP script to respond to my jQUERY ajax call but implement the code within my drupal module.

**My problem is establishing the connection between jQUERY and DRUPAL i:e the function which responds to my CLICK EVENT.**

I was using the following code:

```
function staff_filter_menu(){
    $items = array();
    $items['staff/filtering/results/%'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'staff_filter_function',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'delivery callback' => 'staff_filter_deliver',
    );
    $items['staff/filtering/saveclipboard'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'staff_filter_savetoDB',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'delivery callback' => 'staff_filter_deliver',
    );
    drupal_flush_all_caches();
    return $items;
}
```

But, it stopped working when I stopped, uninstalled and restarted the module. It seems to not be a reliable strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drupal_flush_all_caches()` does this:

> Empties cache tables, rebuilds the menu cache and theme registries, and invokes a hook so that other modules' cache data can be cleared as well.

When the menu is rebuilt, `hook_menu()` is called...basically you're causing an infinite loop by putting `drupal_flush_all_caches()` where you currently have it.

Comment: I see your point Clive but the reason I am calling drupal_flush_all_caches there is because the menu I was attempting to create (the first one above) was not created. After flushing cache an unreasonable number of times, it finally was created ... so I 'forced it' by clearing cache from my code. ALSO, is this the best way to provide an AJAX callback in Drupal?

Comment: @sisko Do you mean using the `delivery callback` method? If so then yes I think that's the best way to do it...the core AJAX functions seem to do it like that :)

Answer (score 1):

You are still creating a loop where your menu items are being called, then cleared by the cache. If anything it should be called first, although there is another problem if you require this in your module's hook_menu().

You should remove that, and make sure your form is calling and returning data using fixed data.